# revertendo custo médio de um produto

Tags: php

Estou calculando o custo médio de um produto usando php.
Eu consigo calcular o custo médio sem problemas, o erro ocorre quando tento reverter o cálculo.

Meu código retorna isso:

```
Novo cuto médio é: 36,56 

O custo médio antigo é: 38,35
```

Sendo que o correto seria isso:

```
Novo cuto médio é: 36,56 

O custo médio antigo é: 35,24
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a localizar o problema? Segue meu código:

```
    $custo_antigo = 35.24;
    $estoque_antigo = 100;

    $custo_compra = 36.23;
    $estoque_compra = 133;
    $encargos_compra = 1.33;


    // Calcula custo médio do produto
    $total_em_estoque = $estoque_antigo * $custo_antigo;
    $total_do_estoque = $estoque_antigo;

    $total_em_compra = $estoque_compra * ($custo_compra + $encargos_compra);
    $calculo_valor = $total_em_estoque + $total_em_compra;

    $calculo_estoque = $estoque_compra + $total_do_estoque;
    $custo_medio_final = $calculo_valor / $calculo_estoque;

    // Formata numero
    $custo_formatado = number_format($custo_medio_final, 2, ',', '.');

    echo "Novo cuto médio é: $custo_formatado <br><br>";


    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    $custo_antigo = 35.81;
    $estoque_antigo = 233;

    $custo_compra = 36.23;
    $estoque_compra = 133;
    $encargos_compra = 1.33;

    // 1º Pega valor do estoque antigo
    $qtd_antiga = $estoque_antigo - $estoque_compra;

    // 2º Total atual
    $total_geral = (($custo_antigo + $encargos_compra) * $estoque_antigo);

    // 3º total da compra 
    $total_compra = ($estoque_compra * $custo_compra);

    // 4º pega custo antigo
    $custo_antigo = ($total_geral - $total_compra) / $qtd_antiga;


    // Formata numero
    $custo_formatado = number_format($custo_antigo, 2, ',', '.');

    echo "O custo médio antigo é: $custo_formatado";
```

Comment: Não entendi por que reverter se já possui o original lá em cima.

Comment: isso e um exemplo, na situação real eu não tenho a original, que e perdida de acordo com as entradas do estoque.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para conseguir reverter precisa de guardar o `$calculo_valor` e o `$calculo_estoque` do primeiro bloco de cálculo.
Por esse motivo, chamarei `$valor_antigo_2` e `$estoque_antigo_2` às variáveis no segundo bloco que se referem a elas.

Para reverter o cálculo precisa de reverter cada um dos valores, e isso poderá ser feito da seguinte maneira:

```
$estoque_antigo = $estoque_antigo_2 - $estoque_compra;

$custo_antigo = ($valor_antigo_2 - ($estoque_compra * ($custo_compra + $encargos_compra))) / 
                ($estoque_antigo_2 - $estoque_compra);
```

Ou seja, o código passa a funcionar assim:

```
$custo_antigo = 35.24;
$estoque_antigo = 100;

$custo_compra = 36.23;
$estoque_compra = 133;
$encargos_compra = 1.33;

$total_em_estoque = $estoque_antigo * $custo_antigo; // 3524
$total_do_estoque = $estoque_antigo; // 100

$total_em_compra = $estoque_compra * ($custo_compra + $encargos_compra); // 4995,48
$calculo_valor = $total_em_estoque + $total_em_compra; // 8519,48

$calculo_estoque = $estoque_compra + $total_do_estoque; // 233
$custo_medio_final = $calculo_valor / $calculo_estoque; // 36,56429...
```

Revertendo:

```
$estoque_antigo_2 = $calculo_estoque; // 233
$valor_antigo_2 = $calculo_valor; // 8519,48

$estoque_antigo = $estoque_antigo_2 - $estoque_compra; // 100

$custo_antigo = ($valor_antigo_2 - ($estoque_compra * ($custo_compra + $encargos_compra))) /
                ($estoque_antigo_2 - $estoque_compra); // 35.24
```

Comment: muito bom, porém não funciona de eu alimentar varias vezes o produto, e cancelar tudo. Ou seja o preço nunca volta para o que era antes. O que devo fazer?

Comment: Como disse no início da resposta, precisa de guardar o valor e estoque resultantes de cada um dos cálculos. Se realizar o cálculo várias vezes sem reverter, precisa de guardar os dados para cada um deles e utilizá-lo ao reverter.
Se precisa de reverter muitos cálculos eu recomendo que não utilize este "processo e retrocesso", simplesmente guarde os dados numa tabela de histórico e busque esses dados quando precise deles.